# Getting style.php to take precedence over style.css

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm currently having problems getting theme options to override the default css settings in style.css. This is what I currently have in my header.php:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='all' href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>"/>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='all' href="<?php get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/style.php"/>
```

I know that since style.php is lower that it should take precedence and override any conflicting rules. I'm not entirely sure if I'm writing the style.php correctly. This was done based off some sources I found online. Here's what it currently has:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/css");
$hi = ot_get_option('category_color');
?>

.category-label {
background: <?php echo $hi; ?>;
}
```

If there is a better way to do it, please let me know!

Comment: Perhaps you should read this article about using a Child Theme.  http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure of what you are asking. I am assuming you want the styles in your php file to override rest of styles.

One simple fast solution is to add `!important`

```
.category-label {
background: <?php echo $hi; ?> !important;
}
```

Why are you using php to include styles. If you want different styles for browsers or screen sizes etc I will recommend media queries.

Also I would not use `header` on the first line

Comment: That is correct. I want my styles in my style.php file to override my default style (style.css). I have a ui builder in the backend of wordpress that allows the user to change the color of the background. I'm trying to get that color that they choose to override the default css. However, I've tried !important and no luck.

Comment: how are you implementing loading of new styles

Comment: I'm using an plugin called OptionTree. The code ot_get_option('category_color'); returns a hex value of the color from the ui builder.

Comment: are u sure that the changed styles are loading in the browser? use figurebug or dev tools to see the styles are loading correctly.

Comment: Yes, I've printed out the results on a separate page and they are loading correctly. I'm just having a hard time getting that into style.php. I also just tried changing the background to black in style.php. No luck. Would it be a formatting issue in style.php?

Comment: The link is http://maleficent.thememonkee.com/. I'm trying to change the category tags in gold to a different color. I can retrieve the hex value I want from the backend, but it doesn't change when I put it in style.php.

Comment: dude use firebug or dev tools. your style.php is not loading at all

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Had to change my style.php to include the following:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/css");
    include("../../../wp-load.php");
    header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
    $catcolor = ot_get_option('category_color');
?>

.category-label {
    background: <?php echo $catcolor; ?>;
}
```